# Mac Air plays music whenever I push on the areas beside the trackpad

Tags: macos, mac, audio, itunes

Whenever I put pressure on the areas beside the trackpad, or even brush them with my hand, my music starts to play. The same thing happens when I adjust my headphones or move them around the jack. Even as I type this post and rest my hands on them, the music just randomly plays.

Sometimes it even starts playing when I put it down on a countertop or table. Quitting out of iTunes doesn’t help, it just relaunches whenever I do any of the above things and starts playing music.

Has anyone experience something like this before? Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Have you tried different headphones?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you have a broken headphone jack or some kind of short between the headphone jack and the MLB. The short is having the same effect as pressing the middle button on the remote on the headphone cord.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you could try to get a more certain answer, although I'll agree with @Spiff and say it's probably a hardware issue of some sort. You could try running [Apple Hardware Test / Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18765?locale=en_US) to see if it reports any immediate issues. To 100% completely rule out software, if you have an external drive, install OS X to it and if the same thing happens in another partition then hardware is the likely culprit.